# Django application models on different databases

Tags: python, django, orm

I have two django apps, call them `Main` on server `A` and `Tasker` on server `B`.
`Main` responds to user requests and does a lot of things that can be quickly done.
On the other hand, `Tasker` only has a few models for logging and celery tasks.

On server `A`, 'tasker' is not included in `INSTALLED_APPS` as I don't need it there, whereas on server `B`, it is.

From [django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/), i create a router and defined `db_for_read` and `db_for_write`

```
class ModelsRouter(object):
    """
       Logging models are on local,
       but updated models are on another server
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
       if model._meta.app_label == 'tasker':
           return 'tasker'
       return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
       if model._meta.app_label == 'tasker':
           return 'tasker'
       return None
```

On server B, `DATABASES` setting contains two keys:

- `default` pointing to server A
- `tasker` pointing to localhost

The problem I have is that when i run `manage.py migrate`, the models of `tasker` are created on server A.
How can I set the project on server B to be aware of the following:
 - models of `main` app are on server A
 - models of `tasker` are on server B (also localhost) ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem the following way:

- I modified ModelsRouter to use `main` database configuration if models are NOT from app `tasker`
- on the server where I deployed `tasker`, I modified `DATABASES` so as `default` points to `localhost` and `main` points to the other server where `main` resides

On server B, I ran `manage.py migrate tasker` as the other models are not needed in that database.
It's working now:

- logging is done in tables on server B
- updates are performed on the other server

The problem I ran into when running `manage.py migrate tasker` is this:

```
RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.
```

but i'll manage it.